# Weird icons on Leaflet map between app WebView and Chrome web browser

Tags: android, kotlin, leaflet, android-webview

I built an app that uses webview to display a leaflet map (which is accessible in any web browser). For some reason, icons are not showing up or showing as a shadow in the app WebView but not in the web browser.

The first image is taken in Chrome. The second image is a screenshot of my app's WebView of the same URL. Any ideas???

[image: Screenshot of Chrome web browser]
[image: screenshot of webview]

Comment: Are you running both on the same emulator/device? Have you checked for errors with: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/

Comment: Hard to say with so little information and no [mcve], but looks like it might be an image format issue, seeing that only the transparent ones are affected.

Comment: This question is lacking, at the very least, the (complete) markup+CSS for the faulty icons plus version information about the webView environment. It's also prone to a divide-and-conquer approach: reproduce the results without a Leaflet map (just the icon markup), then fix that.

Comment: The URL is accessible at www.fireweatheravalanche.org/fire/. It runs fine on Pixel 5 API 32 (Android 12) emulator, but the icons are screwed up on my physical Pixel 6 running the same API version.